# Anylogic Problem: two operators with different operation time in one machine

Tags: simulation, anylogic, event-simulation

I am struggling to resolve a simulation problem in Anylogic.

Problem: 
1. I want to make 2 operators which work in the same machine to have different operation time (for example, when a part arriving at the machine, worker1 spend 3 minutes but worker2 spend 5 minutes.) I have tried the resource pool but the 2 workers that are seized always spend the same time at the machine.

How can I modelize this problem by using flowchart blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Seize ---Service---Delay---Release structure (assuming worker1 spends the 3 mins at the start of the processing).

The Seize/Release blocks seize and release worker2. The Service block represents worker1 working for 3 mins. The Delay block covers the remaining 2 mins for already-seized worker2.

You do it like this (rather than with 2 Service blocks, the first using worker1 and worker2 for 3 mins, the second using worker2 for another 2 mins) because you want to ensure worker2 doesn't get seized by another request when the first Service block ends. (In some models this eventuality won't be a problem so you can use two Service blocks instead but I wouldn't because the way here makes explicit that the *same* worker2 worker is held for the whole 5 mins.

You can also put all this in a custom block (check the AnyLogic help) so it's a reusable single block.

Comment: Many thanks Stuart! I follow your suggestion to use service block to represent worker1, by doing this, would it be possible to find the worker 1 and 2 utilisation? as my ultimate goal is to optimise the number of workers in the production line.

Comment: The `utilization` function of the resource pool gives the utilization of the pool as a whole. Each individual resource unit has function `getUtilization` to get its 'personal' utilization (see Library Reference Guides --> Process Modeling Library
--> Resource functions in the help), but that requires creating the resource units as custom resource (agent) types in a custom population (not the default population) so you can easily access them outside of the process flow. If the two workers are in different resource pools (with only 1 unit in each) you don't need to worry about this 2nd method.